# How do I position different elements that are part of the same div element on the same line horizontally?

Tags: html, css

How do I position different elements that are part of the same `div` element on the same line horizontally? I want to create a navigation bar at the top of my website that contains the logo at the left, the search bar with the search button at the center and the login dropdown menu at the right but I'm not able to align the three elements, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code the styles of your div:

```
display: -webkit-box
display: flex
width: 100%
margin-right: auto
margin-left: auto
-webkit-box-pack: start
-webkit-justify-content: flex-start
-ms-flex-pack: start
justify-content: flex-start
-webkit-box-align: center
-webkit-align-items: center
-ms-flex-align: center
align-items: center
```

Comment: Your code positions them horizontally but I want the login button to be on the right, close to the right margin of the page, how can I do?

Comment: Add 'position: absolute' and 'right: 15px' to the login button class

Comment: Try adding `position: absolute` to the nav div & `position: relative`  to the login button

Comment: You should probably use `justify-content: space-between;` to get the desired alignment.